# Error message: > Could not create service of type FileHasher using BuildSessionServices.createFileHasher(). > java.io.FileNotFoundException

Tags: android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, godot

I've been trying to export my Godot app to a .aab to upload to the play store. I've successfully exported the first version of this, but exporting the second version after some edits to the code causes this error. The edits to the code makes it run without error in the Godot editor so I don't think the edits were the problem.

[Here is the error message I am getting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/At0V0.png)

Does anyone know how to solve this? I tried to locate the file using the finder(I'm using macOS) but couldn't find it.